# How to sync audiobooks using iTunes Match/iCloud from macOS to iOS 11?

Tags: ios, itunes, icloud, itunes-match, audiobook

I have a couple of audio books on my MacBook which I want to listen to on a Road Trip. I imported the files in iTunes and then changed the media type to "Audiobook".

Now they show up as an audiobook, but it seems they won't get uploaded to the iCloud.

**Q: Do I have to label the files as normal Music files with the genre "Audiobook" to be able to listen to them on the go**, or is there a way to upload audio books to iCloud?

How does the iCloud in general handle audiobooks by the way? It seems in earlier versions of OS X and iOS I could just upload the files via iTunes Match.

Answer (score 1):

[iTunes Match](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204146) will only sync music.

**Yes**, in order to upload an audio book using iTunes Match to make it available on your other devices you need to **change thy media type to "Music"**.

I subscribed to iTunes Match when it became available in 2011 and can't remember being able to sync anything but songs. The same is also true for Voice Memos.